# Cor() function giving me and error that the standard deviation is zero

Tags: r, correlation

I am trying to run a correlation matrix on a data frame using the following code:

```
data <- raybio %>% select(4:20, 23:112)
data <- as.matrix(data)
mydata.cor <- cor(data, method = "pearson", use = "complete.obs")
```

I keep getting the following error:

```
Warning message:
In cor(data, method = "pearson", use = "complete.obs") :
  the standard deviation is zero
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Before coercing to matrix run `data %>% summarise(across(everything(), sd)) %>% select_if(~ sum(.) == 0)`. If the standard errors are zero, the vector's Pearson correlation with any other vector cannot be computed due to a [division by zero](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlation#Pearson's_product-moment_coefficient) error.

Comment: Or in other words, you have a column containing only one unique value. You can't calculate a correlation with this column.

Comment: Cor(x,y)=Cov(x,y)/[sd(x)*sd(y)]. If your sd(x) or sd(y) is zero, then division by zero is not defined. The standard deviation of a Constant is zero.